# What process is running with Processid:{1EF75F33-893B-4E8F-9655-C3D602BA4897} via DllHost? It eats up CPU and RAM on a continuous basis

Tags: windows, security, process, process-explorer, security-warning

I'm curious if anyone knows what COM service is using `Processid:{1EF75F33-893B-4E8F-9655-C3D602BA4897}`? I've noticed that my RAM usage went up to 96%, and is still growing. (Mind you, I have 32GB of RAM in this desktop.) When I bring up task manager, I see that `DllHost.exe` or "COM Surrogate" has been using 12% CPU for the last hour or so. Everything else is quiet.

It is 2 PM now so I don't think there's any background process that is scheduled by Windows 8.1 to do any background tasks now. (If so, then it would be a very stupid design!)

I installed and ran [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer) and it gave me this command line that `DllHost.exe` was started with:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\DllHost.exe /Processid:{1EF75F33-893B-4E8F-9655-C3D602BA4897}
```

Now I need to know what this {1EF75F33-893B-4E8F-9655-C3D602BA4897} is. Is there a tool that Microsoft provides to decode this cryptic GUID?

Answer (score 2):

I found it here: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\AppID\{1EF75F33-893B-4E8F-9655-C3D602BA4897}`

That shows it to be "*TIManagersProxy Class Application*".

When I asked Acronis about this in connection with a support request I had previously logged, they declined to answer.

Comment: Dude, getting rid of acronis true image was the best thing I could've done to my computer! Seriously. How can I forget errors like [this](https://i.imgur.com/W2BeVst.png) or [this](https://i.imgur.com/5XZs0ae.png). Awful software. It was running at [constant CPU usage](https://i.imgur.com/BMlb7RA.png) and their tech support were just trying to upsell me for a new version. And it didn't go down easily. It messed up my OS too when I was trying to uninstall it. So yeah. Never again!

Answer (score 1):

Google knows that this is the ***Acronis Sync Agent***.

Comment: OK, thanks. Where did you find it? Does it show why it's doing it in the middle of the day and what's the purpose of it?

Comment: I just googled the ID and found multiple matches with that reference. After a quick read, I considered it correct.

Comment: Hmm. I just read about that "Acronis Sync Agent" and it's designed to synchronize local files with the Acronis cloud.... It's all good, except that I don't use Acronic cloud! WTF?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is it. I just stopped "Acronis Sync Agent Service" and it did nothing. DllHost is still running at 13% CPU and my RAM is still at 99%. Post the Google link that you're referring to. If I search for `{1EF75F33-893B-4E8F-9655-C3D602BA4897}` it does not come up with `Acronis Sync Agent`